# Ros nodes port number

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our application has multiple nodes and currently ROS assign node numbers by default.

Since our application is going to be in public domain I would like to limit the number of ROS node port numbers thats being created.

For example:- I would like to setup something like all my ROS nodes should use port numbers between 3000-4000.

Is there any specification that I can use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268213/ros-nodes-port-number/) by [ros_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/31009/ros_a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked before and as far as I know this is not possible.

ROS uses the regular TCP/IP stack of your OS and does not do anything special to request specific ports.

You could see whether limiting the *ephemeral* port range used by Linux works, but know that limiting it as you are suggesting can potentially lead to problems.

---

Edit: see #q12206 for a related / basically a duplicate of this question.

---

Edit2:

> Since our application is going to be in public domain [..]

do you mean *public domain* as in licensing, or on a publicly accessible IP?

If the latter: you probably already know, but there is no security (ie: authentication, auditing, encryption, etc) in ROS1, so make sure you take sufficient measures to protect your infrastructure.

Would a VPN not work?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/31009/ros_a/) on 2017-08-07**:
Right, we are currently running on a VPN but just want to see if we can limit the port creation..Thanks for your response.